# asp.net jquery load data dynamically when scroll down

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session

I am tryin to load new items to e-commerce website when scroll down to the bottom. I am doing most part of it but it gets the same data to load... I am passing a counter(via session) to select new rows but it doesnt work.

here is the jquery code...

```
function sendData() {
<% Session["count_of_rows_displayed"] = Convert.ToInt16(Session["count_of_rows_displayed"].ToString()) + 1; %>
alert('<%= Session["count_of_rows_displayed"].ToString() %>');
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "insaat.aspx/GetData",
        data: "{'number_of_rows':'" + <%= Session["count_of_rows_displayed"].ToString() %> +"'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: "true",
        cache: "false",

        success: function (msg) {
            $("#myDiv").append(msg.d);
        },

        Error: function (x, e) {
            alert("Some error");
        }
    });
}
```

here is the webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
 public static string GetData(String number_of_rows)
 {
int no = Convert.ToInt16(number_of_rows);
string resp = string.Empty;
SqlConnection connection = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
int i = 0;
connection.Open();
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP " + (no*6) + " * FROM (SELECT TOP " + ((++no) * 6) + " * FROM Product ORDER BY id ASC) t ORDER BY id DESC", connection);
adapter.Fill(ds);
connection.Close();

for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1 && i < 24; i++)
    // build the data 

connection.Close();
return resp;
}
```

I am trying to increment session and pass it with jquery. But it doesnt increment the session. How can I get session incremented ?

Comment: Perhaps this might help you... http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-data-while-Scrolling-Page-down-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't change with each successive call to the AJAX web method:

```
data: "{'number_of_rows':'" + <%= Session["count_of_rows_displayed"].ToString() %> +"'}",
```

That line was rendered to the page *once* with whatever value was in `Session["count_of_rows_displayed"]` at that time.  So every time the AJAX call fires, it uses the same original value for `number_of_rows`.

Since you're tracking this server-side in the `Session` object, you probably don't need to pass the value from the client-side anyway.  Just reference `Session["count_of_rows_displayed"]` and increment its value directly in the server-side web method.

Something like this:

```
public static string GetData()
{
    string number_of_rows = Session["count_of_rows_displayed"];
    int no = Convert.ToInt16(number_of_rows);
    Session["count_of_rows_displayed"] = no + 1;

    // the rest of the method
}
```

**Update:** You say that web methods can't access `Session`?  Well, I guess I haven't encountered that since I haven't found a need for `WebMethod` and I religiously try to avoid using `Session` :)

In that case, and this is probably the better approach overall, you can still use your intended RESTful approach of passing the value to the web method each time.  However, you'll need to also *increment* that value on the client-side.

The original mistake you were making was in thinking that the code is going to re-render that line which references `Session` more than once.  So instead of relying on `Session` to store this value, you should render it to a JavaScript value and then operate from that.  Something like this:

```
var rowCount = <%= Convert.ToInt16(Session["count_of_rows_displayed"].ToString() %>;

function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insaat.aspx/GetData",
        data: {'number_of_rows': rowCount },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: "true",
        cache: "false",

        success: function (msg) {
            $("#myDiv").append(msg.d);
            rowCount++;
        },

        Error: function (x, e) {
            alert("Some error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: but since the getdata() is webmethod, it cannot access to Session. Thats why I am trying to do something....

Comment: It can't?  Geez.  Well, I have an idea.  I'll update the answer with it.  Stay tuned...

Comment: I am trying to use a hidden field now

Comment: @Borsel: Answer updated.  A hidden field also works, yes.  The point is simply to store the value client-side and remove the `Session` dependency entirely.